# Android Studio Emulator Snapshot "Incompatible with the current configuration"

Tags: android-studio

I'm running Android Studio (Flamingo) on macOS Ventura. I had a snapshot saved of an emulator which I'd like to open, but I get the error "Incompatible with the current configuration" in the Manage Snapshots window. I know I had fiddled with the device settings, but I can't remember what they were when I created the snapshot.

I can see in the snapshot folder on my drive, and in it there's a hardware.ini file which has things like `hw.ramSize = 4096`, etc, so I tried changing the device settings to match but doesn't seem to have solved the isssue. Anyone know a way I can find out what the snapshot is expecting the device config to be?

Comment: I've gotten a little further with this but hit a new error. Managed to get the settings back to how they were when the snapshot was created, so it doesn't immediately see it as an incompatible device - but when pressing play to load the snapshot the error "Operation failed due to: Device 'userdata' does not have the requested snapshot '[snapshot_name]" Snapshot load failure: snapshot doesn't exist" - athough the snapshot does exist, since I can see the folder on my drive.

Comment: Still tinkering with this in the hope that I can get this specific snapshot to open. Launching from the command line and using -snapshot-list on my AVD shows the snapshot I want to open, but it says "List of partial (non-loadable) snapshots on 'encrypt':" followed by my snapshot, and then again "List of partial (non-loadable) snapshots on 'cache':". In the first mention it says the VM Size is 827M, but the second says 0 VM. Any ideas anyone?